# how to use orWhere() with where in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to use orWhere after where and whereIn but if orWhere is true it returns data . It should first check where and whereIn data is present according to those condition only then it should check orWhere .

Here is the query

```
   $staff_ids = Staff::select('id')->where('name','like',"%{$request->keyword}%")->pluck('id');
       $work_order_ids = WorkSheet::select('work_order_id')->where('worker_data','like',"%{$worker_id}%")->pluck('work_order_id');
       $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::whereIn('status',[8,9])->whereIn('id',$work_order_ids)->where('id',$request->keyword)->orWhereIn('ranch',$staff_ids)->orWhereIn('cutting_company',$staff_ids)->get();
```

There are the conditions which must check

```
whereIn('status',[8,9])->whereIn('id',$work_order_ids)->where('id',$request->keyword)
```

These are orWhere in which any one of them can be true

```
->orWhereIn('ranch',$staff_ids)->orWhereIn('cutting_company',$staff_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$work_orders =  WorkingOrders::whereIn('status',[8,9])
->whereIn('id',$work_order_ids)
->where('id',$request->keyword)
->where(function($q) use($staff_ids){
  $q->whereIn('ranch',$staff_ids)
    ->orWhereIn('cutting_company',$staff_ids);
})
->get();
```